# overwrite saved file adobe acrobat

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have a form that has to be saved twice, once as incomplete form and the second as the completed form. Is it possible to overwrite/delete the first incomplete file after completing the form so that I wouldn't have 2 forms after the whole process?

I've thought of using javascript but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: You have tagged this question under JavaScript. However, you have not mentioned anything in regards to JavaScript in your question. Please refer to [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use...

```
this.saveAs(this.path());
```

...to save the file and overwrite the existing version. However, the method can only be executed during a batch or console event or some other privileged context. You'll need to reference the Acrobat JavaScript documentation to decide which method of establishing a privileged context will work best for your workflow.

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJSPreface%2FPrivileged_versus_non-privileged_context1.htm%23XREF_76421_Privileged_versus